# Подчеркивание каждого символа вводимого текста внутри input

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Я пытался сделать ввод текста с подчеркиванием каждого символа в `input`, который выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что я не могу реализовать это подчеркивание.

Есть ли какое-нибудь элегантное решение (или не совсем уж плохое)?

Я уже думал об установлении абсолютных позиций и приведении их в соответствие с каждым символом, но я не уверен, что это лучшее решение.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/57219326/7394871

Comment: Ждите нормальной реализации `text-decoration-skip:spaces` в браузерах;)

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете рассмотреть использование `background`, но значение будет тесно связано со свойствами шрифта.

Я применил моноширинный шрифт, который логически даст нам ожидаемый результат, поскольку все символы будут иметь одинаковый размер:

```css
input {
   padding:10px 5px;
   border:1px solid;
   font-family:monospace;
   width: calc(8*(1ch + 5px));
   font-size:20px;
   letter-spacing:5px;
   background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,blue 0 1ch,transparent 1ch calc(1ch + 5px))
    bottom/100% 2px content-box no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="8">
```